# Mounting multiple external HDD storages as /mnt/sdx might cause I/O error on wake from suspend?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, suspend

I have 3 3.5 inch harddisk and plan to use them as storage server.

I first linked two of them as Jbod, and another as independent, then plugged them into two seperate 2.0 usb ports.

Usually I prefer to mount devices as naming sdx like /dev/sdx into /mnt/sdx, so I mounted Jbod one as sdb and another as sdc.

Everything works fine, until the Jbod one goes into the suspend and when I re-access the storage. It freezes so when I try to reboot, it shows "I/O write error on block xxxx, async failed.." messages.

I first thought it was caused by bad sectors of the HDD, But when I reboot I found the mount order has been changed, like Jbod one is sdc instead of sdb.

So I changed mount type to be mounted as UUID of the device, like /mnt/"UUID".

Till now it is working fine from the suspend, but

Is it the right approach for the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

UUID is the preferred method because /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc, etc. can change between boots.

It's described in detail here: [persistent_block_device_naming](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/persistent_block_device_naming)